# Text Filters on two string, But exclude some possibilities

Tags: excel, vba, filter, string-matching

I need to apply a text filtering on the string **`Mod*`** followed by **a specific one character** e.g `"H"` , like: 
  
 (`Mod h`) , (`Mod xxx H`) , (`Module x H`) , (`Mod H`) , (`Model xx H`)  and so on. 
**But**: There are some unwanted cells are included on the result because it includes the string `"Moderate"` ,like:
 `(Moderate , Moderately)`. 
So, I added a second filter to excludes that specific string `"<>*Moderate*"` 
**The problem**: is that some cells could contain `“Moderate”` and `Mod` followed by one character, Like: 
`Moderate xxx Mod H` and subsequently are not includes on filtered data.
 although I need that cells on the expected result. 
this is a test sample:

| ID Description |
| --- |
| beside chemical module h at eastern side |
| all moderately at mod H&B and north |
| Replace moderately at mod C&B and north |
| between Mod. A & Mod. H |
| Five moderately h pipe |

and this is the expected result:

| ID Description |
| --- |
| beside chemical module h at eastern side |
| all moderately at mod H&B and north |
| between Mod. A & Mod. H |

This is my code , I need to overcome this obstacle.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
 
Sub Filter_Critr()
 
    Const critr1 As String = "*Mod*H*"
    Const critr2 As String = "<>*Moderat*"
 
    Dim ws As Worksheet, LRow As Long, rng As Range
 
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
 
     LRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      Set rng = ws.Range("A2:J" & LRow)                   'Source Range to apply Filter on it
 
    If Not ws.AutoFilterMode Then rng.AutoFilter          'Set AutoFilter if not already set
     ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
 
     rng.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=critr1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=critr2
 
       ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
       ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
 
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think that you will be able to achieve this with a normal Autofilter ...

Comment: You can do this relatively easily with Power Query, available in Excel 2010+, if that is an option for you.l

Comment: Please, clarify the meaning of the next part: *"`Moderate xxx Mod H` and subsequently are not includes on filtered data.
although I need that cells on the expected result."* Do you need such cases in the returned result? If so, which to be the meaning of exclusion? If the cells do not contain the enumerated strings (`Mod h`) , (`Mod xxx H`) , (`Module x H`) etc. they will be excluded, anyhow...

Comment: @FaneDuru **(1)** I am basically need to filter on the string `Module` ,but the end users can type it on many ways like (`Mod ,Module`) or even type wrongly like (`model ,modal`) .**(2)** in Work, we have many type of this **Module** like (Module A ,Module B , Module H ,...).

Comment: @FaneDuru , So I provided my below code to find all possibilities of (`Module H`)

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld ,Please could you provide an illustration?

Comment: About Mod `mod`, `module`, `modal`, `model` followed by a space and `h`, I would say it is clear. But **you did not clarify the "moderate" issue, at all**... Should it not be taken in consideration, anymore?

Comment: @Faneduru , When I created my code, I thought it just need to use this `"*Mod*H*"` as criteria , But later I found that words like (Moderate,Moderately) are included. So I added an additional criteria to exclude it `"<>*Moderat*"` and that is the problem, because I need all variants of `Module` like I described earlier ( even if it includes (Moderate, Moderate)

Comment: OK. I will adapt the `arrCrit` content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with more than 2 criteria other than exact matching is not possible with autofilter. Instead, what about an helper column? For example, using a regular expression to be very explicit. Here is an example:

```
Public Function RegexMatch(str, pat) As Boolean

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .pattern = pat
    RegexMatch = .Test(str)
End With

End Function
```

Called at the worksheet level with:

```
=RegexMatch(C2,"\b[Mm]od(?!erate).*\b[hH]\b")
```

- `\b` - Word-boundary to assert that what follows is not preceded by other word-characters;
- `[Mm]od` - Upper-/lowercase 'm' followed by 'od';
- `(?!erate)` - Negative lookahead to assert position is not followed by 'erate';
- `.*` - Any (0+, greedy) characters other than newline;
- `\b[hH]\b` - Match upper-/lowercase letter 'h' and assert that it's a single letter substring with word-boundaries.

See an online demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/kHjvgb/1). Now you can refer to these boolean values in your autofilter.

Comment: On the Regex.Pattern, you used double **H** `[hH]`.
I replaced it with just one H `[H]` and added `.IgnoreCase = True` ,It works but I do not know is it a prober way or stick with your answer.

Comment: @Waleed, it really depends on your further needs. `.IgnoreCase = True` would mean not only 'H' is recognized in both upper/lower-case; but any other character is treated the same way. In your case the 'OD' and negative lookahead are then also treated case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

I also think that `Autofilter` is not able to do what you need. But `AdvancedFilter` should do it...

An unplesent aspect of `AdvancedFilter` is the fact that it needs a criteria `Range`, which cannot be replaced by an array. But, based on an array, such a range can be created, set and deleted at the end. Please, try the next code:

```
Sub AdvFilter_Critr()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, LRow As Long, LCol As Long, rng As Range, rngCrit As Range, arrCrit
   Const filtCol As Long = 3 'column to be filtered
   
   'build the criteria array, based on what to create a criteria range, which is able to admit more than two criteria strings using wildcard:
    arrCrit = Array("=""=*Mod h*""", "=""=*Mod. h*""", "=""=*Mod?? H*""", "=""=*mod??? h*""")
   
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.cells.AutoFilter 'completely clear AutoFilter...
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData              'clear AdvancedFilter...
    
     LCol = ws.cells(2, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column 'last col on the second row
     LRow = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      Set rng = ws.Range("A2:J" & LRow)
      ws.cells(3, LCol + 2).Value = rng.cells(filtCol).Value 'copy the criteria column header
      ws.cells(3, LCol + 2).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(arrCrit) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrCrit) 'build the criteria range
      Set rngCrit = ws.cells(3, LCol + 2).Resize(UBound(arrCrit) + 2) 'set the criteria range
       
      rng.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, rngCrit 'place the advanced filter
    
      rngCrit.Clear 'clear the helper criteria range
End Sub
```

The above code assumes that **the headers row is the second one**!

Comment: yes the headers row is the second one. I am using **AutoFilter** all the time on my works ,but it has disappeared (arrows). also, there is unwanted cell found on the filtered result ,with my provided example (`Replace moderately at mod C & B and north`)

Comment: @Waleed But it has an ending `h` in "north". It is inside your defined pattern "`Mod xxx H`"...

Comment: you are correct (I just found a another problem). *Please*, could you continue you help?

Comment: @Waleed Yes, if I understand what those 'another problem` means. But only after i will be at home. Now, I am leaving my office...

Comment: @Waleed Please, test the updated code. Now, besides the new strings in `arrCrit`, the criteria range is placed starting from the third row. Just in case, if the code is stopped for some reason and the criteria range is  not deleted, calculated `LCol` will not be affected...

Comment: I tried on my real workbook and found that the code did not catch some wanted cells. Like "`to modules (F, G & H)`" and "`of Mod-H to HDR`". It seems I have to use `Regex` option. Anyhow, grateful for your help ,up-voated.

Comment: @Waleed Yes, but it looks that your 'real workbook' does not match your requirements. "`modules`" was not mentioned between the necessary patterns, I cannot understand what `(F, G & H)` should mean, `Mod-H to HDR` does not match you enumerated patterns where `" h"` should be the ending. Then `RegEx` is not something reading your minds, neither. I think I will be able to prepare pattern strings to match your recent requirements, but it started to look as a never ending story. I wish you success in solving your problem! Using `RegEx` or something else. You need to clearly explain what you need.

Comment: Kindly could you help in this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75436036/udf-regular-expression-to-match-a-string-variants-with-some-exclusions) , to not confused, the provided answer by "FunThomas" is what I need , but it is a little slow ( even my function `RegexMatch` is faster than it)

Comment: Please, If you aren't already prepared a code, you can forget my request ( as I already got a Regex function answer on a relative question)

Comment: @Waleed OK. I did not come on stackoverflow being busy. Did you ask a similar question here, or on another forum? If here, please place here a link. I very seldom use RegEx, but I could understand the code I could see. I would like to see it and learn. If not from here, can you share it somehow, please? I would like to see more complex patterns to dig on their understanding...

Comment: I got the regex answer here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75444762/how-to-use-three-negative-lookahead-in-regex-pattern-vba) , But I wonder How a Regex function to be faster than a normal string function, like the answer I got from "Funthomas" in this question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75436036/udf-regular-expression-to-match-a-string-variants-with-some-exclusions)

Comment: @Waleed Well, it depends when the way it is designed. How many conditions should be checked... RegEx is usually slower if a standard VBA solution does not involve many `Ifs`. But if you use arrays and drop the result at once, **not using the function as UDF**, the difference will not be significant. I never use UDF! They load Excel a lot if acting on big ranges and other formulas also exist. A lot of changes in the sheet trigger all such functions in all the workbook. I run the code only **when I need changes for a specific range**.

Comment: @Waleed I followed the link but I could not see there any answer involving `RegEx`...

Comment: The Regex Function is the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75444762/how-to-use-three-negative-lookahead-in-regex-pattern-vba) , and it is exactly the same string function which I got from "Funthomas" in this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75436036/udf-regular-expression-to-match-a-string-variants-with-some-exclusions)

Comment: @Waleed I studied it now, after reaching home and (for me) the optimum matching  pattern for examples you show (on the other question) would be the next: "\b[Mm]od(?!er|if).*[\W_][hH]\b". To only exclude words (strings) as "moderate" ("er" following "mod") or "modified" ("if" after "mod")...

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, this can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

  - *I believe the comments are clear enough that you could add other conditions if needed.*

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID Description", type text}}),
  
    #"Select Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", (rw)=>
      let
  
      //replace punctuation with <space>
            t1 = Text.Replace(rw[ID Description],"."," "), 

      //put spaces around the ampersand and make string all lower case
      //  since PQ is case sensitive
            t2 = Text.Lower(Text.Replace(t1,"&"," & ")),

      //split into a list of substrings by space
            split = Text.Split(t2," "),

      //select all words that start with mod and do not contain "erate"
            #"mod variations" = List.Select(split, each     
                  Text.StartsWith(_,"mod") and not Text.Contains(_, "erate")),

      //find position of first mod or valid mod variant
      //  will return -1 if not found
            #"First mod" = List.PositionOfAny(split,#"mod variations",Occurrence.First),

      //find position of last "h"
            #"last h" = List.PositionOf(split,"h",Occurrence.Last)
      in 

      //test to see if string is valie
            #"First mod">-1 and #"last h" > #"First mod")

in
    #"Select Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: I followed your steps exactly,But it dose not work.I got this error `Expression.Error: The column 'ID Description' of the table wasn't found`. Anyhow, coding inside (power query) is difficult than I imagined. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Waleed That error means the obvious. Your actual data does not have the same column name as you showed in your `Test Sample` in your question. It should be relatively simple for you to make the appropriate changes in the code, but if you have other solutions that are easier for you to use, then by all means use them instead.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect solution as it involves editing the source data before filtering it. However if you're ok with changing "C&H" to "C & H" in the data (so the H is always surrounded by spaces or at the end of the string)

```vb
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
 
Sub Filter_Critr()

Const critr1 As String = "*Mod* H *"
Const critr2 As String = "*Mod* H"
 
Dim ws As Worksheet, LRow As Long, rng As Range
Set ws = ActiveSheet
 
LRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws.Range("A2:J" & LRow)                   'Source Range to apply Filter on it
 
If Not ws.AutoFilterMode Then rng.AutoFilter        'Set AutoFilter if not already set
ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

rng.replace "&", " & "
rng.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=critr1, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=critr2

ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
 
End Sub
```

Comment: I have no problem to add space to `&` (before and after it). But your answer still not overcome the problem of string `“Moderate"`