# Evaluate a range with Regex expression and avoid Offset

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I have used this expression on the cell (K3) `=RegexMatch(C3,"\b[Mm]od(?!erate).*\b[hH]\b")`.
Then I have used it on column (K) respectively with the values of column (C).
I need to use evaluate instead of this. 
I have used the below code, But it dose not work as expected, as I got `#VALUE!` on all `Range("K3:K" & LRow)` 
**Notes**:
 1- I am using office 2016, So I have to use `Index` with `Evaluate` To force the return of an array. 
2- I need to replace `rng.Offset(0, -8).Address` with a prober one if possible.

```
Public Function RegexMatch(str, pat) As Boolean
   With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .pattern = pat
    RegexMatch = .Test(str)
  End With
End Function

Sub Evaluate_Regex()

 Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, LRow As Long

 Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
 LRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      
 Set rng = ws.Range("K3:K" & LRow)    'the helper column
    
 rng.Value = Evaluate("INDEX(RegexMatch(" & rng.Offset(0, -8).Address & "\b[Mm]od(?!erate).*\b[hH]\b""),0)")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a `RegexMatch`-function in your VBA code? Excel itself does not have that function.

Comment: @Ike , yes it is found as a public function , kindly see the accepted answer on this question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75207267/text-filters-on-two-string-but-exclude-some-possibilities)

Comment: When you say you "need to use evaluate instead of this", it is just a mean to achieve something else; what is your final goal?

Comment: `RegexMatch` returns a boolean value - how should that work as first parameter in the `INDEX`- formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking to store you initial values in an array which you can loop over. For example given your sample data in linked question:

[image]

You could apply:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long, x As Long: lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim r_in As Variant: r_in = ws.Range("A2:A" & lr).Value
Dim r_out() As Variant: ReDim r_out(1 To UBound(r_in), 1 To 1)

For x = LBound(r_in) To UBound(r_in)
    r_out(x, 1) = RegexMatch(r_in(x, 1), "\b[Mm]od(?!erate).*\b[hH]\b")
Next

ws.Range("B2:B" & lr).Value = Application.Index(r_out, 0, 1) 'Application.Transpose would have limits

End Sub

Public Function RegexMatch(str, pat) As Boolean

Static RE As Object: If RE Is Nothing Then Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = pat
RegexMatch = RE.Test(str)

End Function
```

[image]

---

A 2nd option would be to evaluate the formula directly over the entire range:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long, x As Long: lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

ws.Range("B2:B" & lr).Formula = "=RegexMatch(A2, ""\b[Mm]od(?!erate).*\b[hH]\b"")"

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it works, But I tested it on just 3K rows and it finished on about 7 seconds, is that a normal speed?

Comment: Regular Expressions take time. I'm not sure how to speed this up further. I'll edit in a 2nd option to do this, and you can benchmark the solutions yourself @Waleed

Comment: it is the same time ( about 7 seconds) , anyhow grateful for your help 

Comment: A probably minimal increase in speed could be to use a lazy match quantifier in the pattern itself: `.*` should become `.*?` @Waleed. Other than that, I wouldn't know. [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) could be a place to ask for improvements to bump up speed.

Comment: If you use `Static RE As Object` in the first example then you don't need to create a new object for each evaluation and you'll get a huge speed-up.  For ~1000 values my timing went from 3.3 sec to <0.1 sec

Comment: @Tim Williams ,I can confirm your suggestion is brilliant. on my test with ~3000 values my timing went from 7 sec to **0.05 sec** 