# UDF (Regular expression) to match a string variants with some exclusions

Tags: regex, vba, string

I need to use (Regular expression) on the string `Mod*` followed by a specific one character e.g. "A" , like:

`Mod A`  ,  `Mod_A` ,  `Module xx A`  , `Modules (A & B)` and so on.

But, with the following conditions:

**(1)-** if the cell contains any of  (`Modif*` or  `Moder*` or `Modr*`)  and  `Mod*` Plus my specific character then the result is **True** 
**(2)-** if the cell contains any of  (`Modif*` or  `Moder*` or `Modr*`)  and not `Mod*` Plus my specific character then the result is **False**

Please this example and the expected result:

| **Item Description** | **Expected Result of RegexMatch** |
| --- | --- |
| new modified of module A 1 | TRUE |
| new modification of mod A | TRUE |
| new moderate of mod_A | TRUE |
| to modules (A & B) | TRUE |
| new modified and moderate A 1 | FALSE |
| new modification of A | FALSE |
| new moderate of modify | FALSE |
| to modules (D & E) | FALSE |

```
Public Function RegexMatch(str) As Boolean
  Dim tbx2 As String:  tbx2 = "A"   'ActiveSheet.TextBox2.Value
    Static re As New RegExp
      re.Pattern = "\b[M]od(?!erate).*\b[" & tbx2 & "]\b"
       re.IgnoreCase = True
         RegexMatch = re.Test(str)
End Function
```

In advance, great thanks for your kindly help.

Comment: Why should `new modification of  A` be FALSE?

Comment: Your 4th example doesn't contain Modif* or Moder* or Modr*

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew ,If it is `new modification of  module A` then it will be TRUE. OR, if it is `xxx module A` or `xxx Mod xxx A` also true.

Comment: @FunThomas ,yes it's intended

Comment: Then I don't understand the logic that the 6th example should be false. It also contains `Mod*` and `A`

Comment: Try `^.*\bMod(?:ules?)?[\W_]*A\b` (`"^.*\bMod(?:ules?)?[\W_]*" & tbx2 & "\b"`)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew , there's a syntax error on the pattern

Comment: [Can't see any](https://regex101.com/r/Qac4dB/1).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew , Please I got confused, I mean the `Pattern` in your above comment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Maybe because VBasic Regex implement a slightly different logic: https://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew , it has incorrect result with this string "`to modules (F, G & A)`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your requirements correctly: You want rows that contain a word that starts with "mod", but words starting with "Modif" or "Moder" or "Modr" doesn't count. Additionally, a module *character* (eg "A") needs to be present.

I usually get dizzy when I see longer regex terms, so I try to program some lines of code instead. The following function replaces special characters like "(" or "_" with blanks, splits the string into words and check the content word by word. Easy to understand, easy to adapt:

```
Function CheckModul(s As String, modulChar As String) As Boolean
    Dim words() As String
    words = Split(replaceSpecialChars(s), " ")
    
    Dim i As Long, hasModul As Boolean, hasModulChar As Boolean
    For i = 0 To UBound(words)
        Dim word As String
        word = UCase(words(i))
        If word Like "MOD*" _
        And Not word Like "MODIF*" _
        And Not word Like "MODER*" _
        And Not word Like "MODR*" Then
            hasModul = True
        End If
        If word = modulChar Then
            hasModulChar = True
        End If
    Next
    CheckModul = hasModul And hasModulChar
End Function

Function replaceSpecialChars(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    replaceSpecialChars = s
    For i = 1 To Len(replaceSpecialChars)
        If Mid(replaceSpecialChars, i, 1) Like "[!0-9A-Za-z]" Then Mid(replaceSpecialChars, i) = " "
    Next
End Function
```

Tested as UDF with your data:
[image]

Comment: I run a quick test and works perfectly. I will test on my real dataset and feed you back.

Comment: I tried your code against my regex function `RegexMatch` , **and strangely** your function is slower than regex (Both functions tested in an array to get the fastest speed)

Comment: I tested this with 1m rows (in memory) and it took < 4s on an fairly old computer.