# How to use three (Negative lookahead) in regex Pattern VBA?

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I am using this regex Pattern `"\b[Mm]od(?!er).*\b[hH]\b"`

- `\b` - Word-boundary to assert that what follows is not preceded by other word-characters;
- `[Mm]od` - Upper-/lowercase `m` followed by `od`;
- `(?!er)` - Negative lookahead to assert position is not followed by `er`;
- `.*` - Any (0+, greedy) characters other than newline;
- `\b[hH]\b` - Match upper-/lowercase letter `h` and assert that it's a single letter substring with word-boundaries.

**Basically**, I  want the cells that contain a word that starts with "`mod`", but words starting with "`Modif`" or "`Moder`" or "`Modr`" doesn't count.

Additionally, a module character (eg "`H`") needs to be present.

**So**, in addition to the existing negative lookahead `(?!er)` , I need to add two additional negative lookahead ("`Modif`" , `Modr`") to the pattern.

Please this example and the expected result:

| **Item** | **Expected Result of Regex** |
| --- | --- |
| new modified of module h 1 | TRUE |
| of mod H | TRUE |
| new of mod_H | TRUE |
| new moderate of mod_H | TRUE |
| to modules (A & h) | TRUE |
| new modified and moderate H | FALSE |
| new modification of A mod_A | FALSE |
| to modules (D & E) | FALSE |
| to mode (F, G & A) | FALSE |

```
Public Function RegexMtch(str) As Boolean  

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

        .Pattern = "\b[Mm]od(?!er).*\b[hH]\b"

        RegexMtch = .Test(str)

    End With

End Function
```

As always, I am grateful for all your help.

Comment: So, just add them as alternatives: `"\b[Mm]od(?!e?r|if).*\b[hH]\b"`. Note that the word boundary before `[hH]` will prevent `mod_H` from matching. You need to use `[\W_]` there. See https://regex101.com/r/k7LdbY/1. `\b[Mm]od(?!e?r|if).*[\W_][hH]\b` must work for you.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew ,It works perfectly. You can post as the answer (if you like)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\b[Mm]od(?!e?r|if).*[\W_][hH]\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k7LdbY/1). Note that the word boundary before `[hH]` in your pattern prevents `mod_H` from matching, so you need `[\W_]` there.

**Pattern details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[Mm]od` - `Mod` or `mod`
- `(?!e?r|if)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `er`, `r` or `if` substring immediately to the right of the current location
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `[\W_]` - any char other than a letter or digit
- `[hH]` - `h` or `H`
- `\b` - word boundary